# Adding a separator to the Eclipse Outline view (like #pragma mark)

Tags: eclipse, outline-view

I know Xcode has a

```
#pragma mark
```

feature where it allows you to insert arbitrary labels in outline views / method lists to document how code is segmented.

I haven't been able to find a similar feature for Eclipse.  I can't help but feel that it's right under my nose, but searches on both SO and Google haven't been enlightening... anyone know how I might do this?

Or is there some hackish workaround? That would be awesome too.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Eclipse outline view supports categories (with @category in javadoc) for showing additional information on methods. See the following screenshots for an example of such usage.

[image: Category definition in the editor]

[image: Category and filtering in the Outline view]

Unfortunately grouping by categories has not been implemented yet. There is an [open feature request](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=132326) for this, but it is nearly four years old and clearly stated that it needs community effort. Personally I do not know such plugin.

Comment: This is why we keep saying do not outsource information on this website. I find a possible useful answer but here it is, the link is dead.

Comment: The dead link was removed and replaced with some screenshots. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 9):

**The horror:**

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private int _______________________________________;
```

Or if you prefer labels:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private int _______________Lifecycle_______________;
```

[image]

Bonus points for varying the number of underscores so you can have many separator lines.

---

***My Android Studio Version***

Use code regions:

```
//region

    ... your code here ... 

//endregion
```

Bonus points for making the folded presentation look like a comment:

```
//
//region // Lifecycle

   ... your code here ...

//endregion
//
```

[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Neither does that of @ntle

Comment: Maybe, but his answer did not come up flagged in my stream in the 'needs review' as a 'low quality' answer.

Comment: There you go, I just flagged it

Comment: Actually, I think this is the best answer - though it only gives a work-around.  I wonder if it will work similarly when I switch to Android Studio (some day).

Comment: This is the closest anyone came to providing what was asked for... as horrifying as it may be.

Comment: Perhaps you should use methods instead of fields to reduce memory usage, like `@SuppressWarnings("unused") private void _______________Lifecycle_______________(){}`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use "Add Bookmark".

One way to do that is to right-click on the left side (where line numbers are shown), and select "Add Bookmark...".

You can view them in "Bookmarks" view.

Answer (score 4):

In order to mimic the `#pragma mark` functionality I usually create a dummy method that works as a separator. For example:

```
private static void someDummyMethod(){}
```

Answer (score 0):

#pragma mark is supported natively in Eclipse CDT as of about 2022-06.

```
#pragma mark Public API       // Inserts a bold title
#pragma mark - Public API     // Inserts a line above a bold title
#pragma mark - Public API -   // Inserts a line above and below a bold title
#pragma mark -                // Inserts a line
```